# Was there a concept of investing in Harry Potter's wizarding world?

Tags: harry-potter, economics

I just saw DampeS8N's comment to this question: [What exactly do the Malfoys do for a living?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/what-exactly-do-the-malfoys-do-for-a-living)

> Lots of investing in businesses and basically living off the interest it generates.

Is there any evidence that there's a concept of investing in a business in Harry Potter's world?

Comment: If there is free enterprise, there is investing.  And all one has to do to see if there's free enterprise is walk through Diagon Alley.

Comment: @TangoOversway - Not necessarily. There wasn't much investing in local shops in medieval England, which is where Diagon seems to be based off of. IMHO YMMV

Comment: I was thinking in terms of "does the concept exist?" not so much to what degree, so I was going with a quick off-the-cuff comment, which is why I didn't expand and expound and make it an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. At the very least, Harry invested in [Weasleys Wizard Wheezes](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Weasleys%27_Wizard_Wheezes)

Comment: Yup! That's what I was going to say :)

Comment: I have one small doubt. He provided venture capital, BUT there seems to be no evidence that there's any official equity ownership. Weasleys let him get stuff for free, but that seems to be fore PR purposes.